# How can I slow technological advancement?

Tags: technology, technological-development

**The Scenario**

I am the last survivor of a race of technologically advanced humanoids.
My civilization annihilated itself and devastated our home planet.

**My Capabilities**

I have sole (obviously) kernel level access to the distributed computer system designed to manage the planet and provide for its inhabitants. This computer is integrated into the planet itself, it has no discernible physical presence.

I have the remnant of our solar power arrays, amounting to about 3% of the total solar output of our home star - which is functionally identical to the Sun.

My computer is capable of transforming matter to energy and back.

My computer has the sum total knowledge of my species and is functionally omnipresent within the atmosphere of my planet.

My computer has effectively unlimited computing power/data storage, and is capable of solving problems/carrying out instructions with minimal supervision.

My computer is capable of manipulation at the subatomic level, up to and including building complex structures - such as life forms.

**My Limits**

The philosophical/political group that I belonged to could best be described as Neo-Victorian Romantics.

I have a sincere belief that souls exist, and are generated by the universe when a sentient being is conceived.

I believe that my race was ruined by our grasping for technological advancement at all costs.

Despite technology allowing for mind transference/uploading and/or perfect bodily cloning, it is my sincerely held belief that biological or technological immortality is a wrong and beings should live and die. So my overall lifespan is limited to a paltry 1500-2000 years.

My personal beliefs are that my race has had its chance, and its time is over.

**My Goal**

I would like to create a New World, free from or at least minimizing the problems of the old.

I would like this world to be populated with real, thinking beings - who choose rather than be forced to dedicate themselves to philosophical growth and learning.

I aim to contrive a slower path of technological ascension for the race/races I create as my successors, giving them time to 'mature properly'.

I don't care if I live to see any of this - I could easily just spend 1500 years planning everything with my computer before telling it to 'execute' and letting myself die.

I have no attachment to any remnant of the old world, so nothing is out of bounds as far as planetscaping and biologically rewriting all plant/animal life or cleaning the slate and designing from the ground up.

My successor race(s) however should be humanoidish. Something that would appeal to me aesthetically.

**My Question**

Given my capabilities, what techniques can I use to achieve my goals?

This [How could the 'Totally-not-space-wizards' completely suppress technological advancement](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/70561/how-could-the-totally-not-space-wizards-completely-suppress-technological-adva)

is about the only question I could find that touches on what I'm looking for, but it's not *that* close. Some ideas for thought, though.

Comment: "*the remnant of our solar power arrays, amounting to about 3% of the total solar output of our home star*".  That would require a **LOT** of satellites beaming energy down to your planet.  Did you really mean "3% of solar output **which strikes your planet**?"

Comment: And, unless I missed it: since you're the only one left on the planet... who are you going to breed with?  To get a healthy amount of genetic diversity beyond the **minimum** viable population, you'd want 10-15,000 "people".

Comment: One more thing: how "*devastated (is y)our home planet*"?  IOW, pollution, radiation, flora and fauna, etc?

Comment: Nope, you read it right. The star has a lot of solar stations. And I won't be breeding with anyone, but I can construct entire new 'people'.

Comment: "*I can construct entire new 'people'"*.  You should add that to your question.

Comment: The planet is damaged to the point where few if any technological artifacts remain, but nothing seriously inhibiting long term prospects for life.

Comment: Well, people are made out of matter...

Comment: Well that's not a devastated **planet**... (It is, of course, a devastated **species**.)

Comment: "*Well, people are made out of matter.*"  And yet we're a heck of a lot more complicated than clay.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81165/discussion-between-brizzy-and-ronjohn).

Comment: Your question boils down to, "How does my godlike being produce an intelligent species able to obtain higher wisdom than the old?"  The answer, of course, is "you can't."  Not and still have an intelligent (and presumably free-thinking) species.  You're equating the development of stronger ethics and morality with slower learning.  It doesn't work that way.  It never has.  It's like suggesting experiencing poking your finger into an electrical socket later in life will somehow keep you from wanting to push other people's fingers into the socket.  Nope.

Comment: No, my question is "How can I slow down technological growth" because all the stuff you are talking about is challenging a character's world view and opinions, when he explicitly has no one around to challenge them. Theses are all in character conceits, which is why I phrased things the way I did. I'm not asking if he is right or wrong in his assumptions, he believes he is right.

Comment: 0. Set up your computer to act as a God, instructing people to limit technological growth, promoting "maturation", and punishing deviations. Technological development is a socio-economic thing, so you need to influence how people think. There might be some hard-science factors which I cover below, but their impact is limited.

Comment: 1. Make one large supercontinent with no internal mountains or deserts, so entire world could be controlled by a single empire. Europe became hotbed of innovation due to constant military and economic competition between countries. In constrast, China had single empire for several thousands years, but did not advance nearly as fast technologically.

Comment: 2. Make climate mild enough so food grows on trees (like tropical regions). No need to innovate (just keep rival tribes out of your trees). Or make climate so severe that people are too busy surviving to mess with technology (like arctic regions).

Comment: 3. Make minerals rare, both metals and fuels. That could prevent technological development altogether. Or force them to use biologic materials, which would lead to more environmentally-friendly civilization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Give them a longer life span**

Both in terms of when they die from old age (potential life expectancy), and the actual life expectancy (resource reach planet with abundant food, few natural threats and less deceases).

Why that's a good idea:

1. People stay at their position for longer, not giving way to the younger generations. Longer life cycles leads to naturally slower change (biological, technological, philosophical and so on).
2. Easier and more secure life - less *need* to change.
3. Young people have more time for education, and therefore more time to reach enlightenment and 'mature properly'.

However, note that this while this might make technological progress slower in terms of **years**, this won't necessarily work in terms of **number of generations**.

If you need the second one - I believe you cannot pre-program it. [Technological progress](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_technology) isn't (at all) linear. It's actually *random*. Sometimes it's extremely fast (1850-now), very slow (200-1000 AD), focused in only some fields (ancient Greece) etc. You cannot really anticipate this, only maybe make some changes on the go (but you do not want to do that).

Comment: Perhaps add a slower maturation of the children as well. Having a longer life expectancy but still having children at the same age as before just means accelerated population booms and with it accelerated technology. Also, wouldnt a shortened life expectancy be better? If you have less time understanding a concept and building on that you have less progress per life, and someone like Einstein would be far less influential if he had say 40 years of life to accomplish his feats in.